# Does react-admin v4 supported?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, api-platform.com

Yesterday the [react-admin v4](https://marmelab.com/blog/2022/04/13/react-admin-v4.html) has been released. I quickly tried to create a local version w/ api platform backend and `HydraAdmin` ([@api-platform/admin](https://github.com/api-platform/admin)) frontend. But it seems it does not work because the new version of react-router.

W/o the HydraAdmin it works, but sadly it is not an option for me.

**So, my question is: the api-platform/admin@2.8.3 is supporting the react-admin@4 or not?**

I did not find any information about this w/ my search-friends. (G and Duck) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@api-platform/admin has a v3.0.0-rc that supports react-admin v4.

As far as I can tell, @api-platform/admin v2 only supports react-admin v3.

Comment: Thank you. Not long after your comment, the new version has been released.